# Refreshing rallycombobox after adding new rollup

Tags: rally

I have a rallycombobox that is configured to show the Rollups in the current scope:

```
App.down('#associateWith').add({
    xtype          : 'rallycombobox',
    fieldLabel     : 'Dropdown',
    id             : 'association',
    allowNoEntry   : true,
    storeConfig    : {
        autoLoad       : true,
        model          : 'PortfolioItem/Rollup'
    }
});
```

This app also has an addnew component that enables users to add a new PortfolioItem/Rollup - If they add a new one, then I want to refresh this combobox to have that rollup as an option as well.  I was not able to find a way to refresh the combobox in the API docs, so I am doing the messy version - which involves creating and destroying the combobox quite frequently.

I tried doing a:

```
setStoreConfig(...);
```

But that did not seem to refresh the data at all.  Any way to accomplish this without destroying and re-creating?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to to this is to hook into the AddNew's `create` event. It will give you a record of the newly created Rollup, and from there you can place it in your ComboBox's store

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',

    launch: function() {
        this.combobox = this.add({
            xtype: 'rallycombobox',
            allowNoEntry: true,
            storeConfig: {
                autoLoad: true,
                model: 'PorfolioItem/Rollup'
            }
        });
        this.add({
            xtype: 'rallyaddnew',
            recordTypes: ['PortfolioItem/Rollup'],
            listeners: {
                create: this._onCreate,
                scope: this
            }
        });

    },

    _onCreate: function(addNew, record) {
        this.combobox.getStore().add(record);
    }
});
```